# jquery to javascript translation

Tags: javascript, jquery

Would someone please translate this into regular javaScript:

```
$("div.intro h1").hide();
$("div.intro h2").remove();
```

Thanks.

Comment: Even if jQuery is JS, it's still translation. [StackOverflow is not a code translation service](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129362/177538)

Comment: OK Jospeh. I need to target an h1 element that is inside a div with a class name 'intro' and set its display styling to none in native javascript and not jQuery. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: In fact, I do know how. But what have you tried?

Comment: I tried waiting until someone who is not full of themselves start me on the right track. I am new here. Sorry if you didn't like my question. Thanks for your respone RobG.

Comment: @SammyD Don't take it as a personal attack on you.  StackOverflow values the effort put into a question, not just in asking but the research done prior to asking.  This question is perceived as asking to be spoon fed something that wouldn't be hard to find with resources easily available.

Comment: Thanks Guys. This has been an eye opening experience for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could start by testing for support for querySelectorAll and if found, use that to create an array of elements matching "div.intro h1".

Otherwise, use `getElementsByTagName('div')`, filter for those with a class of "intro", then use `getElementByTagName('h1')` to get the H1 elements and collect them into an array.

Then for each member of the resulting array, set their `style.display = 'none'`.

Do the same to create an array for removal, then for each do `el.parentNode.removeChild(el)`.

Let's see what you come up with.

Comment: Thanks RobG. I ended up doing this: document.getElementById('containerWrapper').getElementsByTagName('h1')[0].style.display = "none";